# Define what makes a code section in rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Rstudio changed how a code section is defined. In version 0.99.902 code sections had to have some text behind the hash symbol. But now in version 1.0.136 if there are 5 hashes in a row it will define a new section.

Is there anyway to make it go back to the old way of defining sections? It isn't a big deal except I would mark my sections with hashes above and below the name and now it is creating 3x as many sections.

Old version:

[image]

New version:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's a way to recover the old behavior, but you could use `+` instead. In addition, you can put this in a code snippet (if you haven't already). In Preferences, go to the `Code` tab, scroll to the bottom and click the `Edit Snippets` button. Then add something like the following:

```
snippet hd
  `r "# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  ### HEAD ##########
  # ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"`
```

Then, when you type `hd` followed by a tab (actually two tabs, since the first tab will bring up a few options that start with `hd`, but `hd` will be at the top, so you can just press tab twice) in your R script file, the following will appear:

```
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
### HEAD ##########
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Better yet, you can create a snippet that takes the heading text as an argument:

```
snippet hd
   `r paste("# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n",
   "### ", "${1:HEAD}", " ##########\n",
   "# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++", sep="")`
```

Then, when you type `hd` followed by two tabs, the `HEAD` text will be highlighted and you can just type in your actual heading text.

Comment: Good tip about the snippets. I didn't know you could do that. I was debating just using a different symbol to avoid the extra sections, but that doesn't help my old code.

Comment: You could do a find and replace to change `#######...######` to `# ++++...+++++` whenever you open an old script. Painful, but at least it's only one operation and needs to be done only once for a given script. If you're handy with the command line, you could do this for all R scripts at once, preferably using regular expressions to capture and replace only "long" strings of `#`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this behavior has changed between RStudio v0.98.1091, v0.99.903 and the current release v1.0.136.

In RStudio v0.98.1091, 'empty' headers such as `#####` were recognized as section headers.

This behavior was briefly changed with v0.99.903, such that some initial text was required for these to be recognized as section headers. A number of users were unhappy as this effectively broke code folding for users who were explicitly using standalone `#####` blocks to create sections.

Because of that, the behavior was reverted in RStudio v1.0.136, and so now standalone `#####` blocks are again recognized as section headers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a post on Rstudio about this?

Comment: I don't think standalone sections with e.g. `####` were ever explicitly documented, but because they worked they implicitly became part of how sections are created in RStudio. The closest thing I can find is this support article: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections

Comment: Where did you find the notes on the changes with each version?